# the index value of attribute

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using the following code

...
 ...

```
for($i=0; $i<90; $i++){
?>
 <a id='read[<?php print $i; ?>]' href="<?php print $textToshow; ?>"> Text Shown</a> 
<?php } ?>
```

I want to know the id of the a href when a user clicks on it. Something like read[1] read[2] etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function( e ) {
   alert(this.id);
   // e.preventDefault(); // Uncomment this line if you don't want
});                       //    to follow the link's href.
```

This assigns a `click` event to *all* `<a>` elements that will alert its ID when clicked.

Uncomment the [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) line to prevent the default behavior of the link (following its `href`).

It would probably be best to add a class attribute to the links, and select using that:

```
$('a.someClass').click(function( e ) {
   alert(this.id);
   // e.preventDefault(); // Uncomment this line if you don't want
});
```

This selects `<a>` elements with the class `"someClass"` using [the class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
$('a[id^=read]').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);

  return false;
});
```

I use the [attribute-starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to target the links that have an `id` that starts with **`read`**