# send the value of id to fancy box

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, fancybox

I have different value for id attribute that I need to send to fancy box.

```
$('a.Links').click(function() {                        
     var clickID = $(this).attr('id') ;
     alert(clickIDID);
}); 

$("#"+clickID).fancybox({
    'width'    : '75%',
    'height'   : '75%',
    'autoScale'   : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
    'type'    : 'iframe',
    'titlePosition'  : 'outside',
    'content'  : 'testl'
});
```

How can I send the value of clickID to .fancy box. I tried to add the .fancybox within click function but that doesnt work. see previous question for detail
[the index value of attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221269/the-index-value-of-attribute)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose all of your IDs begin with the word 'popup_', (popup_1,popup_2 etc.), then you could use the [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector like this:

```
// initialize fancybox for all elements with ID starting with 'popup_'
$("[id^=popup_]").fancybox({
    'width'    : '75%',
    'height'   : '75%',
    'autoScale'   : false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
    'type'    : 'iframe',
    'titlePosition'  : 'outside',
    'content'  : 'testl'
});
```

However, it would be more straightforward to use a class attribute to address them collectively, like this:

```
<a class="popup">Foo</a>
<img class="popup" src="foo.jpg"/>

$(".popup").fancybox({
    ...
```

Comment: problem is that I have idexed values. please see my previous quetion for details

Comment: `$("a[id^=read]").fancybox({...` should do it, unless I'm missing something. Pretty much the same as what I described.